# Bind std::function error

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I face a problem when trying to bind a method with std::function and std::bind.

In my CommunicationService class :

```
this->httpServer->BindGET(std::bind(&CommunicationService::ManageGETRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));
```

CommunicationService::ManageGetRequest signature :

```
MessageContent CommunicationService::ManageGetRequest(std::string uri, MessageContent msgContent)
```

BindGET signature :

```
void RESTServer::BindGET(RequestFunction getMethod)
```

RequestFunction typedef :

```
typedef std::function<MessageContent(std::string, MessageContent)> RequestFunction;
```

The error on BindGET :

> error C2664: 'void
>   RESTServer::BindGET(RequestFunction)':
>   cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'std::_Binder < std::_Unforced,MessageContent (__cdecl
>   communication::CommunicationService::*
>   )(std::string,MessageContent),communication::CommunicationService
>   *const ,const std::_Ph < 1 > & >' to 'RequestFunction'

Before, my RequestFunction was like that :

```
typedef std::function<void(std::string)> RequestFunction;
```

and it worked perfectly. (with all signature methods adjusted of course).

I don't understand what causes the error.

Comment: `ManageGetRequest` takes two parameters plus the `this`.  You only give `bind` `this` and one parameter.

Comment: You're missing a `_2`.

Comment: OK thank you, I should have looked more carefully to documentation, I didn't understand how std::bind was actually working

Comment: as above, plus suggest you avoid std::bind altogether and use a lambda.

Comment: Your fundamental problem is you used `std::bind`.  I get it, it is there, maybe you should use it.  But `std::bind` comes from `boost::bind`, which was written before C++ had lambdas.  Just use a C++ lambda. Really. In C++14, there are very few good reasons to use `std::bind`, as almost all of the few features it had that lambda lacked have been given to lambdas.  `bind` gives cryptic error messages and even after you master it, has extremely strange quirks and traps, like passing the result of `bind` to `bind` breaking everything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
this->httpServer->BindGET(
  std::bind(&CommunicationService::ManageGETRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1)
);
```

to

```
this->httpServer->BindGET(
  [this](std::string uri, MessageContent msgContent) {
    this->ManageGETRequest(std::move(uri), std::move(msgContent));
  }
);
```

Using `std::bind` is almost always a bad idea.  Lambdas solve the same problems, and almost always do it better, and give better error messages.  The few cases where `std::bind` has features lambdas do not where mostly covered by C++14.

`std::bind` was written in pre-lambda C++11 as `boost::bind` then brought into the standard at the same time lambdas where.  At the time, lambdas had a few limitations, so `std::bind` made sense.  But this isn't one of the cases where lambdas C++11 limitations occur, and as lambda has grown in power since, learning to use `std::bind` has significantly diminished marginal utility at this point.

Even if you master `std::bind`, it has enough annoying quirks (like passing a bind expression to bind) that avoiding it has payoff.

You could also fix it with:

```
this->httpServer->BindGET(
  std::bind(&CommunicationService::ManageGETRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)
);
```

but I don't think you should.